# Bash : variable declaration inside while loop to get latest data not working

Tags: bash, prometheus

For testing, I want to test sending data to local 9090 port. I am using a while loop to achieve this. But the while loop is not getting triggered, the script is getting stuck at variable inside while loop. What am I doing wrong?

Code :

```
#!/bin/bash
nc -l -p 9090 &
z=$(ps aux)
echo "ps done"
while true 
do
var=$var$(awk '{print "cpu_usage{process=\""$11"\", pid=\""$2"\"}", $3z}');
echo "var done"  ---> Not getting here
curl -X POST -H  "Content-Type: text/plain" --data "$var" http://localhost:9090/metrics ;
sleep 10;
done
```

This line is not working out

```
var=$var$(awk '{print "cpu_usage{process=\""$11"\", pid=\""$2"\"}", $3z}');
```

Any ideas why? Thank you. :-)

Is there any better way to send such statistics every 5-10 seconds. :-)

Comment: There is no input to the awk command. It is normally a file or a variable through <<< $var. What data are you trying to parse with the awk command?

Comment: awk is waiting for something in standard input. You probably wanted to do something like : var=$(ps aux | awk '{print "cpu_usage{process=\""$11"\", pid=\""$2"\"}", $3z}')

Comment: I would avoid using ps aux. You can also avoid using awk as well by using the native ps formatting and so ....  ps -eo 'cpu_usage{process="%a", pid="%p"} %C'